# Algebraic degree of a product of two algebraic elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> Suppose $(m,n)=1$ and let $a$ and $b$ be algebraic of degrees $m$ and $n$ respectively over $F$. How to prove that $ab$ is algebraic of degree $mn$?

It is easy to prove that $ab$ is algebraic of degree a divisor of $mn$, but somehow I am unable to show that $[F(ab):F]=mn$. In other words, it is enough to show that $F(a)F(b)=F(ab)$.

Comment: See [this](http://www.doiserbia.nb.rs/img/doi/0350-1302/2005/0350-13020591067D.pdf) paper.

Comment: Nice paper, they do it more generally. Is there no easier proof for the situation above? I have been trying to show that $F(a)F(b)=F(ab)$.

Comment: @YACP and how do we somehow conclude that the assumption on $m$ and $n$ being relatively prime does not give us that condition you state as given in the paper?

Comment: @YACP yes you are right, the above question is not true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following counterexample shows that the statement is not true in general. Let $p$ be a prime, and let $a=\sqrt[p]2$ and $b=e^{2\pi i/p}$. Then $a$ has degree $p$ over $\Bbb Q$ while $b$ has degree $\phi(p)=p-1$ over $\Bbb Q$, since their minimal polynomials are $x^p-2$ and $\Phi_p(x) = x^{p-1} + x^{p-2} + \cdots + x+1$, respectively. But $ab$ is also a root of $x^p-2$ and thus has degree $p$ over $\Bbb Q$, not $p(p-1)$.

Comment: I'd like to ask a modified but related question: For two general algebraic numbers a,b, with the number fields Q(a) and Q(b) assumed linearly disjoiint  over Q, is the product ab a primitive element of the compositum of Q(a) and Q(b)? Or does it require any one (or both) fields to be Galois extension of Q?

Comment: What if $a=\sqrt2$ and $b=\sqrt3$?

Comment: Thanks. By changing to a different choice of primitive elements say $a'=1+\sqrt2$ and $b'=1+\sqrt3$, we can see now that $a'b'$ is a primitive element for the compositum. My question in less precise terms, generically is the product of primitive elements again primitive? (for a  'dense set'  of choices in some kind of Q-Zariski topology)

Comment: Probably ... generic elements of any field extension are primitive, I imagine.